# Is there any substitute for SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ping

I have this linux server located overseas, and `PING` response time is very long (about 450ms). When I login with `ssh`, it is very loggy, and I think it is due to slow `PING` ( or the slow network connection).

But the connection speed is OK when I open a website on the server. So I wonder if there is a good substitute for SSH, or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) is good for this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mosh (https://mosh.mit.edu/) is a SSH replacement tool that works well in high-latency scenarios. It does not require a response from the server to do predictive text (or to show typed commands at all) and is pretty nifty.

Note that Mosh is bootstrapped by SSH (uses SSH for initializing the connection and authentication), so it isn't really a disjoint tool, just more of a wrapper to enable a pleasant experience when dealing with high latency.

Comment: `mosh` is certainly a separate tool and not just a wrapper; it merely uses `ssh` to establish the initial connection to start the `mosh` server on the remote end. Once the `mosh` server is running, `ssh` is no longer used.

Comment: Well, to be fair, `mosh` is a wrapper that starts `mosh-server` on the remote end, then runs `mosh-client` locally.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't mean to imply that that [tag:mosh] is not a separate tool, just wanted to be clear that [tag:mosh] does use [tag:ssh]

Answer (score 0):

The ssh flag `-C` can be used to ask for compression from the SSH server, which in some cases may make your connection faster, but is unlikely to be helpful in this case because of what you mentioned about the ping time.

Another flag you might find helpful is the `-c` flag which allows you to request a specific cipher to use from the server, I've heard good things about blowfish for this sort of problem.

To use both of these commands when SSHing you can try this:

```
ssh -C -c blowfish-cbc username@server
```

Finally, there are certain protocols like telnet or rsh (which are considered by many to be obsolete for this purpose) that do not use encryption, which may make your connection faster, at the cost of it being less secure.

Comment: The problem is latency, not bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed the part about ping time, so I changed my answer to reflect this.